# Calculating a circle's area by using two classes

Tags: c#

Its the first time I've used this forum! I'm a second year university student and have just started writing code in C# (as were we did java last year).

One of the lab exercises is to write a small program that pops up a terminal window asks for a number (decimal number) this is meant to be the radius the program calculates the area by calling the method from another class!

I've written the code in Visual Studio 2008, using the same namespace, it builds and runs but doesn't work?
Here is the code with the different classes, any help/advice would be appreciated.

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Program4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter The Radius:");//Text to be displayed in the console
            Console.ReadLine();//Read the line and store information in temp directory
            Pie one = new Pie();//Calls the method from the class in the same namespace
            Console.ReadKey();//Reads and displays the next key pressed in the console   
            Environment.Exit(0);//Exit the Enviromet        
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Program4
{
    class Pie
    {    
        public void Pin ()
        {
            int r;//defining the value that is going to be entered as an integer 
            double result;//declaring the result string as a double
            r = (int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            result=(3.14*r*r);//the calculation to work out pie
            Console.WriteLine("The Radius of the circle is " + (result));//the writeline statement    
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually call the `Pin()` method. And you're calling `ReadLine` twice when you'd only need it once if you were calling `Pin()`.

Comment: You also need to look at your maths. If `result=(3.14*r*r)` then result is NOT the radius as stated by your `WriteLine` in `.Pin()`...

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will revisit the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try running the code:

```
Pie one = new Pie();
one.Pin();
```

**Also:**

this line:

```
Console.ReadLine();//Read the line and store information in temp directory
```

that comment is very wrong. It should be `//Read the line and throws the result away`

and this: `(int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());` 
could be replaced by this: `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`

Answer (score -4):

add static to class Pie and public void Pin(). It will work

```
    static class Pie
    {

          public static void Pin ()
          {
            int r;//defining the value that is going to be entered as an integer 
            double result;//declaring the result string as a double
            r = (int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            result=(3.14*r*r);//the calculation to work out pie
            Console.WriteLine("The Radius of the circle is " + (result));//the writeline statement    
         }
    }
```

or if you prefer you can instantiate the class and then call the method like that

```
Pie pie=new Pie();
pie.Pin();
```

Comment: Changing them to static will not work, not unless you call `Pie.Pin()` which you have not mentioned. It is clear from the question that the user is misunderstanding how class instances and method calls work. So this is what a good answer should be focusing on - teaching the OP how to do things correctly

Comment: @musefan thanks for the answer. As soon i' ve launc break i'll edit and explain the difference